How to be sure the written pins are correctly named for this RS485 terminals?
I have a USB to RS485 converter and it has only two terminals written on it A(D+) and B(D-) no GND.  I also have a USB scope with differential ended inputs. I read in forums that some such converters name A and B incorrect way. And I want to check if A is really A(D+ non-inverting) and B is really B(D- inverting) just by looking at waveforms.
Both the USB scope and the USB to RS485 converter are connected to same PC's USB ports. That means they share the same ground. To test the RS485 terminals I use a program to send serial data so that I can check the A and B lines.
Here is the signal between the A and GND, meaning that A is connected to the positive terminal of the diff ended scope:

Here is the signal between the B and GND, meaning that B is connected to the positive terminal of the diff ended scope:

And here is A minus B, meaning that A is connected to the positive terminal of the diff ended scope and B is connected to the negative terminal of the scope:

In this case how can we conclude the written pins are correct?


How to be sure the written pins are correctly named for this RS485
terminals?

No way can you be sure 100% without testing however...
One thing you can be nearly 100% sure about is that if you use two identical units (same model and supplier) then you connect A to A and B to B.
Of course you can't rule out a few rogue manufacturers getting the label right on one unit and wrong on the other (even though they should have the same internal wiring). Recommendation: buy from reputable suppliers.
On the other hand, you can't rule out that different models or suppliers use different polarities. I've witnessed this but, no panic, I just swapped the wires over on one unit (or the offending unit).

Oh damn:( I hoped there was a way. I thought maybe idle state of A minus B is defined positive or negative in standards.

@pnatk: Yes, looking at the idle level is exactly how you tell the difference (assuming that you know the bus is idle and not transmitting a "break" condition).  But Andy's answer says you cannot know "without testing", and observing the idle level is testing, so there's no contradiction here.

@pnatk The standard does not apply as you are forcibly sending logic high as idle with UART. However from the binary 1 state you can determine that it is called "OFF", A is negative with respect to B.

To be clear, unless you have a manual or schematics from where you can verify the A/B naming, you cannot be sure until you measure yourself, or try connecting it to other equipment both ways until it works (as the other equipment may also use any naming convention).
The RS-485 standard defines the pin names explicitly.
As you seem to know, they can be named differently by different manufacturers.
That is because some RS-485 chip manufacturers use the names A and B differently in their chips.
Your device names them also D+ and D-.
The pin A with D+ is clearly the non-inverting and pin B with D- is clearly the inverting on the oscilloscope view, so you can be sure which pin is which.
In RS-485 standard, the D+ is B though. So your device does label the D+ incorrectly as A.
But you cannot categorigally assume based on Internet forum discussions that all such converters label the pins incorrectly.
For application's sake, UART idles at logic high which you seem to be forcibly transmitting. RS-485 defines binary 1 state as "OFF" where A is negative compared to B. So B is the non-inverted terminal compared to binary data.
There are standarda that base on RS-485 and these standards also define how the pins musr be used or marked - such specs include DMX512 and some industrial bus (I can't remember which of them), but they explicitly stated in the documentation that because they like to adhere strictly to standards they use the same naming convention as defined by RS-485 standard, which is a bit tongue-in-cheek to put into official documentation.

Thank you for great answer. So better to focus on D+ or D- marks. But some transceivers they only mark A and B without D+/-. For example here: https://static-cdn.m5stack.com/resource/docs/products/unit/iso485/iso485_sch_01.webp In this schematic A is pulled up to 5V and B to pulled down to GND correct. Does that mean by looking at the schematic we can say in this case also A is D+(non-inverting) and B is D-(inverting) terminal?

@pnatk Yes that adapter has A as D+. Like I said, you can never trust that A and B are marked correctly on random hobbyist products, or even more professional products. The adapter you linked to is otherwise not even true RS-485 as it is more like a pseudo-CAN-like dominant/recessive transmitter. And it does not directly provide a common ground reference to the bus. It's basically in the category of garbage that may work for some limited purposes, but far from a true RS-485 transceiver.

By garble and pseudo CAN you mean the USB to RS485 adapter in question or the one in schematic in comments? The one in schematic using an isolated RS485 transceiver from TI. But there is a parallel RC between the shield and the GND. maybe you mean that?

@pnatk I mean the one in "m5stack" link is a pseudo-CAN-alike device. And no, shield connection is high impedance. RS-485 chips must have their RS-485 side ground tied together with other RS-485 chips. The bias resistors allow it to work but not connecting grounds together violates RS-485 specification. There is no link to your USB-RS485 adapter, but if it does not have a ground connection, it only works with other devices grounded through your computer to mains earth. If you simply connect A and B wires to a battery powered device, or worse, a mains-powered floating device, it may not work.

Its strange why they put that RC(1Meg 1nF) in between shield and the GND. If they didnt they would provide direct ground.

@pnatk Not that strage. If this was 10BaseT Ethernet with BNC connectors, the Ethernet side BNC interface would connect to PC ground/chassis through 1M and about 1nF as per specs. It allows the bus to have good AC/HF ground
while allowing it to float, limit voltage slew under ESD/EMI and drain accumulated DC bias slowly to earthed PC. That is approximately OK for RS-485 shield too, there is just a terminal missing to allow bonding the bus side GND terminal of the chip to another chip GND terminal.

I see. In their terminals it shows ground instead of shield as the third terminal as here https://static-cdn.m5stack.com/resource/docs/products/unit/iso485/iso485_04.webp and here: https://static-cdn.m5stack.com/resource/docs/products/unit/iso485/iso485_02.webp Maybe in the schematic they labelled that terminal wrong as shield. Hard to guess..

@pnatk If it were ground, it would be directly connected in the schematics. Shield can be AC coupled as you do not want DC return currents passing in the shield but in a dedicated ground wire to equalize potential between chips. Again, know what you need, figure out which device fulfills it. Schematics show shield connection, regardless of terminal name being ground. Device name indicates RS-485 regardless of it not being real RS-485 at all, but pseudo-CAN. Typical for cheap products on hobbyist sites that they don't know what they are really selling.
